# Unexpected reserved word 'await' in getting the session id

Tags: react-native

I want to get the session ID and do the API call.when I try I get this issue, tried so many options adding `ASYNC` but I still get the error. any suggestions

```
const  onRefresh = React.useCallback(() => {
const deviceId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@device_ID')
const sessionId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@session_Id')
console.log('device ID: ',deviceId, 'session ID: ', sessionId)
  setRefreshing(true);
//   wait(5000).then(() => setRefreshing(false));
    try{
    let ServiceTicketData = await fetch(`${API_URL}/v1/serviceTicket`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'apiKey': 'asdkhjfgsed34e',
            'deviceId': deviceId,
            'sessionId': sessionId

        },
    });
    let STData = await ServiceTicketData.json();
    console.log(STData);
    setRefreshing(false)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    
}, [refreshing]);
```

Comment: You need to mark your function as `async`. Like this -- `React.useCallback(async () => ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the function with await keyword with a self calling async function.

```
const  onRefresh = React.useCallback(() => {
const deviceId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@device_ID')
const sessionId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@session_Id')
console.log('device ID: ',deviceId, 'session ID: ', sessionId)
  setRefreshing(true);
//   wait(5000).then(() => setRefreshing(false));

    (async () => {
    try{
    let ServiceTicketData = await fetch(`${API_URL}/v1/serviceTicket`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'apiKey': 'asdkhjfgsed34e',
            'deviceId': deviceId,
            'sessionId': sessionId

        },
    });
    let STData = await ServiceTicketData.json();
    console.log(STData);
    setRefreshing(false)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
})()
    
}, [refreshing]);
```

Comment: Thanks this works. I Added async to 
const  onRefresh = React.useCallback(async() => { too